# Convert Date part of a timestamp value from YYYY/MM/DD to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: sql, database, oracle, timestamp, datetime-format

I have a few timestamp values like this :

2014/02/13 07:45:30 -0800

I want to change them to

13/02/2014 07:45:30 -0800

how do i achieve this?

Comment: stackoverflow is for help on broken code. What have you tried? Good luck.

Comment: You have actual timestamps, or string that look like timestamps? Actual timestamps do not have any inherent format; you choose how to format them when you convert them to string for display.

Comment: As above, guessing you have a string that you want to apply to_timestamp to with a format mask. You could then to_char it with whatever format mask you required.

Comment: As a side note, if you _are_ storing timestamps as strings (and you can't change to using an actual timestamp type)  **DON'T** change the representation in the database to your desired format.  Yours can't be sorted nicely.  Generally, the database should _never_ do formatting - that's a display-layer concern, and in some cases the db may simply not have the relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use a command like this one

```
TO_CHAR(date_value, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
```

This will convert the date to the format you're looking for, if not then you should be able to work with the command to alter it to the correct format.

This does assume that the column is in a date format.

Comment: Well, he's going to be missing the GMT offset, could you add that in?  And possibly 24-hour time, too.

Comment: The missing Offset can be achieved this way -                         TO_CHAR(timestampWithTimezone value, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss TZHTZM')

Answer (score 0):

**Try Thiz :**

`select to_char(to_date(substr('2014/02/13 07:45:30 -0800', 1, 19),'YYYY/MM/DD hh24:mi:ss'),'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') from dual;`